# Switch from one Activity to another one results OOM error on Samsung device

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have one `Activity` with 3 `Fragments` and another `Activity` with 3 `Fragments`. In each `Fragment` I have 10 PNG pictures, each about 8kB in size. When I switch from the first `Activity` to another I get this error:

```
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #78: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at com.uustaga.vista.Fragment6.onCreateView(Fragment6.java:42)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:482)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onInterceptTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:1896)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2033)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2091)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2091)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2091)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2305)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1575)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2470)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2253)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7875)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3976)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3860)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5103)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5082)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5180)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    ... 45 more
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
02-27 00:19:28.973: E/AndroidRuntime(14652):    at android.graphics.draw
```

I've tested the app on a Blackberry 7' tablet, Alcatel OT phones and on Samsung phones and only on the Samsung Core2 I get this crash.

Comment: @ Daniel Nugent this is twilight zone. I saw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021127/binary-xml-file-line-17-error-inflating-class-unknown-caused-by-unsupportedo, doesnt help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried various ways to implement something more creative, such as:

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options ();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    ...
```

to make better prevent the outflow of memory but I had no success. In the end I decided to use

```
    android:largeHeap = "true"
```

under the tag of my application manifest file, and that solved my problem.
Perhaps this solution is not desirable but is effective.